# How do I find where a file is located inside container?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I'm trying to give special permissions to a file located inside a container but I'm getting a "**No such file or directory**" error message.

The Dockerfile basically runs a R Script that generates an output.pptx file located inside an output folder created inside the container.

I want to send that output into a s3 bucket but for some reason it isn't finding the file inside the container.

```
# Make the output directory
RUN mkdir output 

# Process main file
CMD ["RScript", "Script.R"]

# install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install -i /usr/local/bin/aws -b /usr/local/bin

# run AWS CLI to push output file to s3 folder
RUN chmod 775 ./output/*.pptx
RUN aws s3 cp ./output/*.pptx s3://bucket
```

Could this be related to the path I'm using for the file?

Comment: I think `CMD` should be the last line. Move it to the last and then restart or start the container.

Comment: no success :\. I'm not sure if that's it because the output.pptx file is generated when the file is proccessed, so this step needs to be done before sending the output somewhere else

Comment: If this is your dockerfile, and the `Script.R` generates the pptx file, then the file will never be available when you `docker build` the container. I suggest you add a way to upload the pptx file within the `Script.R` file, perhaps using R's `system` or `processx::run`, or perhaps the [`aws.s3`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/index.html) package.

Comment: could you explain why this is @r2evans? because the output is right there when I do "docker cp CONTAINER_ID:/usr/local/app/output ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Edited* to fix a word-swap brain-fart in the first version.)

I get the idea that there is a misunderstanding of how the image should be *used*. That is, a `DOCKERFILE` creates an image, and the `CMD` is not actually run when building the image.

Up front:

- an **image** is really just a tarball with filesystems; multiple "layers" are there, to indicate the layers of the build process (which can be squashed); an **image** has no "running" component, no processes are active in an **image**; and
- a **container** is an image that is in a running state. It might be the `CMD` you specify, or it might be something else (e.g., `docker run -it --rm myimage /bin/bash` to run a bash shell with the **container** as the filesystem/environment). When the running command finishes and exits, the **container** is stopped.

Typically, you create an image "once" (security updates and such notwithstanding), and then run it as needed (either manually or via some trigger, e.g., cron or CI triggers). That might look like

```sh
docker run --rm myimage                 # using the default `CMD`
docker run --rm myimage R Script.R      # specifying the command manually
```

with a couple assumptions:

- the image has `R` installed and within the `PATH` ... though you could specify the full `/path/to/bin/R` instead; and
- the default working directory (dockerfile's `WORKDIR` directive) contains `Script.R` ... or you can specify the full internal path to `Script.R`

With this workflow, I suggest a few changes:

- from the `DOCKERFILE`, remove the lines after `# run AWS CLI`;
- add to `Script.R` steps to copy the file to your S3 instance, either using the `awscli` you installed in the image, or by using the [`aws.s3`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/index.html) R package (which might preclude the need to install the awscli);
- I don't use AWS S3, but I suspect that you need credentials to be able to access the bucket; there are many ways for dealing with images and "secrets" like S3 credentials, the most naïve approaches involve hard-coding the credentials into the container, which is a security risk; others involve "docker secrets" or environment variables. For instance,

  ```sh
  docker run -it --rm -e "S3TOKEN=asldkfjlaskdf"
  ```

  though even that *might* be intercepted by neighboring users on the docker host.